# unable to add check inside map to filter out details

Tags: javascript

updating the value only if matches mnemonic for currentTab which is present in items data without changing original items

```js
let items = [{tab:'tab1',info:[{mnemonic:'first',value:'alm'},{mnemonic:'second',value:'jim'}]},
             {tab: 'tab2',info:[{mnemonic:'first',value:'kim'},{mnemonic:'second',value:'tim'}]},
             {tab:'tab3',info:[{mnemonic:'first',value:'wint'},{mnemonic:'second',value:'telt'}]}]

let expectedOutput = [{tab:'tab1',info:[{mnemonic:'newValue',value:'alm'},{mnemonic:'second',value:'jim'}]},
         {tab: 'tab2',info:[{mnemonic:'first',value:'kim'},{mnemonic:'second',value:'tim'}]},
         {tab:'tab3',info:[{mnemonic:'first',value:'wint'},{mnemonic:'second',value:'telt'}]}]


let currentTab = 'tab1';
let obj = {mnemonic:'first',value:'newValue'}

const getChecked = ()=> {
  const newArr = items
  .map(
     ({ info, ...rest }) => ({ 
       ...rest, info: info
        })
   )
   
  return newArr;
}
 const arr = getChecked();
 console.log('newArr',arr)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) we can achieve this.

```js
let items = [{tab:'tab1',info:[{mnemonic:'first',value:'alm'},{mnemonic:'second',value:'jim'}]},{tab:'tab2',info:[{mnemonic:'first',value:'kim'},{mnemonic:'second',value:'tim'}]},{tab:'tab3',info:[{mnemonic:'first',value:'wint'},{mnemonic:'second',value:'telt'}]}];

let currentTab = 'tab1';
let obj = { mnemonic: 'first', value: 'newValue' };

const updateItems = (items, currentTab, obj) =>{
  return items.map(item => {
  //check if the provided tab is matching with the item.tab
    if(item.tab === currentTab) {
      return {
        ...item,
        info: item.info.map(i => ({
            ...i,
            //update the `mnemonic` if provided object's mnemonic is matching with the item's mnemonic
            ...(i.mnemonic === obj.mnemonic && { mnemonic: obj.value })
        }))
      }
    } else return {...item}
  })
} 

console.log(updateItems(items, currentTab, obj))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```